# how to call multiple classes [lets say modules] for a single job in php

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, module

in a CMR project which manages Radius authentications (create user, renew user, delete user, expire time, etc)

I want to create user in multiple accounting servers such as free radius , mikrotik user manager radius etc ...
I already developed the API for those accounting servers 
the thing I can't figure our is that how I should call a method to trigger i.e. a method called create_user() in all modules (free radius.inc.php , userman.inc.php ) to create a user in all accounting servers.

lets say create_user() method exists on all of them .

I also want to add more accounting server classes to the project later , i don't want to hard code for another accounting support implementation

thanks in advance

Comment: I know I have to use parent child classes , but I don't know a flexible method .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if if i understand what you mean but let's give it a try. To abstract your `accounting servers` you should use an interface.

```
<?php

interface AccountingServer {

    public function create_user();
}

class Server1 implements AccountingServer {

    public function create_user()
    {
        echo "Create user on server 1";
    }

}


class Server2 implements AccountingServer {

    public function create_user()
    {
        echo "Create user on server 2";
    }

}

$server1 = new Server1();
$server1->create_user();

$server2 = new Server2();
$server2->create_user();

?>
```

If you mean to share the `create_user()` method in all your `accounting servers` you should use parent-child structure.

```
<?php

abstract class AccountingServer {

    public function create_user()
    {
        echo "Create user";
    }
}

class Server1 extends AccountingServer {

}

class Server2 extends AccountingServer {

}

$server1 = new Server1();
$server1->create_user();

$server2 = new Server2();
$server2->create_user();

?>
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks m8 , thats exactly what I was looking for :) 
But I don't know how to call : 
$server1 = new Server1();
$server1->create_user();

$server2 = new Server2();
$server2->create_user();

in a loop from a database 

shall i give function variable to modules name ? 
and call in database row loop so it will create user in all accounting servers ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give an example of a database row and explain what your goal is?

Comment: Thanks for reply , 
I have a create_user method in class1 which creates user in free radius 
and another one on class2 which creates user in IBSng radius server

i want to create user in both of them simultaneously or by order 
class1 and class2 are inserted to database's module table and flagged as active 
another class lists modules ... 
I want to create user in both of class1 and class2

Comment: Do you mean you want to create an instance of e.g. Class1 based on a value in your database?